# How to make row of images resize and fit one row on mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Kind of a dumb question but I can figure it out. I'm working on my portfolio site and I have icons of software languages that I excel in (bootstrap is supposed to be one of them).

I just want these images to display in a single row, and resize based on the screen size.

Here's some code that I've been trying:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="max-width: 100%">
        <img style="height: auto; width:64px" src="/images/html5.png"  />
        <img style="height: auto; width:64px" src="/images/divide.png"  />
        <img style="height: auto; width:64px" src="/images/bootstrap.png" />
        <img style="height: auto; width:64px" src="/images/divide.png"  />
        <img style="height: auto; width:64px" src="/images/c.png" />
        <img style="height: auto; width:64px" src="/images/divide.png"  />
        <img style="height: auto; width:64px" src="/images/Unity.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's how it looks on mobile:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
img {
  display: inline-block !important;
  max-width: 12% !important;
}
```

Border-box includes the padding and borders in the width and the 14.28% * 7 images = 99.96% of the width. You could also use:

- 14.285% * 7 images = 99.995%
- 14.2857%* 7 images = 99.9999%
- 14.285714285714285714285714285714% * 7 images = 99.999999999999...%

Answer (score 2):

With [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), you need to use multiple `col-*-*` classes on your div in order to achieve such result.

The purpose of those classes are to provide you different presentations based on the size of your screen (and furthermore, the presentation on each device - following the [responsive design principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)).

You can find more information on [this interesting article](http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/08/bootstrap-3-grids-explained/), and [this one too](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/).

As Chris Happy pointed out, this can be achieved using percentages in CSS. But this is what also Bootstrap does in behind, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It is worth checking it out, very handy and powerful framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, you wrapped the whole page in one div container. It is really important when using bootstrap that you use div container to every different section of your page. So for example before 'row' use another container (try the fluid one if the normal one doesn't work). And don't forget to close the divs in the right place to differentiate your sections properly! 
Bootstrap is a grid system so you have to structure your page in sections.